Is it possible to define all figures in one place at the end of my latex file and call them wherever I want to place them?
I have a long latex file with some 20 figures. I want to define all the figures in one place so that it is easier for me to find them in latex and edit them. I can define all the figures at the end of my document or beginning or in a different figures.tex file if need be. And then I want to call them in the body of the main document wherever I want to place them. Is it possible to do this?

Using float package and specifying [H] won't help since then all the figures will be placed at the end.
This answer does not help me since it only shows how to hide/display a subset of figures.
I found this solution from ChatGPT that defines each figure as a command and then calls them where required, but the comments suggested this approach is not good.

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Are these external images or things like tikz pictures or plots?

These are external jpg images. I add them to latex using figure environment

this really is a duplicate question to the one that you reference, you are just asking for comments on your answer there, but the question is the same question

So what are you editing exactly?

@DavidCarlisle, there is a difference in the two questions. For the referenced question, having 20 tex files, one for each figure, is acceptable. For my case, it is not. My answer to that question based on ChatGPT solution is what I am after. And yes, because the comments suggested that the ChatGPT answer has problems, I wanted to ask a separate question for that.

@cfr, Steven's solution and this ChatGPT solution is exactly what I want to do. However the comments on the ChatGPT solution said that it is not recommended. So, I am looking for alternate ways to achieve the same thing.

Maybe something like this, using \Savefigure{...} and \Nextfigure[...], where all the figures are defined at the beginning of the document (in the preamble, even).
EDITED to add error checking in \Nextfigure to make sure the myfigcnt counter does not exceed the value of svfigcnt.
By not explicitly specifying a name or number in the invocations allows one to add, remove, or rearrange figures without messing up some perceived naming convention.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\newcounter{svfigcnt}
\newcounter{myfigcnt}
\newcommand\Savefigure[1]{%
  \stepcounter{svfigcnt}%
  \expandafter\def\csname myfig\thesvfigcnt\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand\Nextfigure[1][t]{%
  \stepcounter{myfigcnt}%
  \ifnum\value{myfigcnt}>\value{svfigcnt}
    \par\fbox{FIGURE NOT DEFINED.}\par
  \else
    \begin{figure}[#1]\csname myfig\themyfigcnt\endcsname\end{figure}
  \fi
}
\Savefigure{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Image A}
}
\Savefigure{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Image B}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\Nextfigure[h]
\lipsum[2]
\Nextfigure[h]
\lipsum[3]
\Nextfigure
\end{document}


ADDENDUM
If one truly desired to be able to apply naming labels to each figure, one could do it as such:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\newcommand\Savefigure[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname myfig#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand\Recallfigure[2][t]{%
  \ifcsname myfig#2\endcsname
    \begin{figure}[#1]\csname myfig#2\endcsname\end{figure}%
  \else
    \par\fbox{FIGURE ``#2'' NOT FOUND}\par
  \fi
}
\Savefigure{imagea}{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is Image A}
}
\Savefigure{imageb}{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This is Image B}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\Recallfigure[h]{imagea}
\lipsum[2]
\Recallfigure[h]{imageb}
\lipsum[3]
\Recallfigure[h]{another figure}
\end{document}



Great. But how is this different from the solution that ChatGPT gave in the answer I have referenced: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/715090/178369

@NagabhushanSN The difference is that, in your referenced solution, the figures are given specified names such as \figureTwo.  If one is editing their draft document and wished to insert a new figure prior to it, the naming convention becomes confusing.  In my approach, that is not an issue.

@NagabhushanSN Also, this version doesn't save the float into a definition. The float is created at the time it is called. I'm guessing that should be a little bit safer (more robust). However, you might want to add some provision for labels.

It's still going to be a PITA if you need to restructure the document, though.

@StevenB.Segletes you're right. However, I need not use command names as \figureTwo. I can name the figures like figureComparisonDatasetLlff and so on and call them wherever I want. It will be easier to reorganize figures too.

@NagabhushanSN Please see my ADDENDUM to my answer.

Oh! This is nice. @StevenB.Segletes does this allow including numbers in the figure names? Like, can I replace imagea with image1? Some of my datasets have numbers in them (Eg: MipNerf360). The ChatGPT solution does not allow numbers. So, I use just MipNerf which might become confusing at some point.

@cfr, can you please elaborate on what you mean by "ChatGPT solution saves float into the definition, but this answer does not and creates float when it is called"? What are the pros and cons of the two approaches? If you can share any references, that is also fine.

@NagabhushanSN \Recallfigure doesn't literally recall a figure. It constructs a figure and puts a 'saved' image/caption into it. Actually, I don't think it really does that either. It uses a macro which expands to the stuff needed to create the image/caption. It is not like saving it into a box and then using the box, for example. If you use the same figure ten times, it will be constructed ten times, whereas a box would just be copied ten times.

@NagabhushanSN yes, the image "label" can include all alphanumeric characters.
